# Problem Installing Ubuntu LTS 20.4.1 on a system with a software Raid - Grub-install fails (error: failed to get canoncial path of '/cow')

Tags: system-installation, grub-efi

Problem Installing Ubuntu LTS 20.4.1 on a system with a software Raid - Grub-install fails (error: failed to get canonical path of '/cow')

The error stems from grub-probe and it is an enigma for me:
I have no clue what /cow is and how this error message is created.

I am trying to install Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.1 LTS from a live-USB stick using EFI-Mode. All HDDs and SSDs are using GPT-Partitioning.

```
grub-install --verbose /dev/nvme0
```

runs until grub-probe is called and exits with the error message (also contained in the title)

> grub-install:error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow`

The system is a Tuxedo Mini-PC (German Manufacturer from Augsburg, specialised in Linux PCs) with 2 HDDs in RAID 1 and one additional SSD (NVMe). OpenSuse Leap 15.1/15.2 and Tumbleweed boot without a glitch even when using an EFI partition on the software raid.

At first I thought adding an SSD not connected to a RAID will solve the issue, but it does not, even if all install partitions are located on the SSD.

Any help is appreciated. Especially by someone knowing the Grub source code who can tell what exactly leads to this error message.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

Step 1: disconnect the RAID (all harddisks connected to the BIOS-Raid).

Step 2: Install Ubuntu 20.04.1 on the SSD (using partitions with ext4 filesystems). Using a harddisk might work as well.

Step 3: After the installation: Reconnect the harddisks. The motherboard BIOS (in my case AS-Rock) does recognise that there was a RAID and shows it without having to reinstall anything. Most importantly no data is lost.

In case you want the installation of Ubuntu to reside on a mirrored disk:

Step 4: Copy the partitions from the SSD to the RAID (in case you want) using an USB Live system (I used PartedMagic).

Step 5: Adjust /etc/fstab

Step 6: With the tool efibootmgr adjust the booting partition to the raid.

Speculation as to what caused the problem:

It seems it was a parsing error of grube-probe with the grub version supplied by Ubunto, which does not occur on Suse Leap/Tumbleweed. That means there have to be differences in the source code between these two distributions.

Statements:

1. Ubunto 20.04.1 cannot be installed on systems with a software RAID, whether it is supported by the BIOS or generated by a linux distribution.
2. But Ubunto 20.04.1 does run on systems with a software RAID, just the installation is not supported because the version of grub that is used by Ubunto does not support them. The call that fails is grub-install which in turn calls grub-probe which is the ultimate reason for the failure (most probably due to parsing errors).